# Owasp Zap: spider scan stops at 99%

Tags: owasp, zap, security-testing

Owasp Zap: spider scan stops at 99%. and not getting completed 100% even after waiting for long time. Please help me!
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Mvgs.jpg)

Comment: i am facing the same issue, is there any solution ?

Comment: not found any solution yet! Let me know if you will get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set the depth to 1 or 2. Go to Tools -> Options -> Spider, then move the depth slider to 2.